# 'NSDictionary' may not respond to '-objectAtIndex:'

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary

There are no bugs in the code but my Dictionary doesnt get loaded

**CODE:**

```
//
//  SectionsViewController.m
//  Sections
//
//  Created by Kunwar Handa on 25/05/11.
//  Copyright 2011 Fortune4  Technologies. All rights reserved.
//

#import "SectionsViewController.h"

@implementation SectionsViewController
@synthesize names;
@synthesize keys;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIViewController Methods

-(void)viewDidLoad{


    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sortednames" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    self.names= dict;
    [dict release];

    NSArray *array = [[names allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    self.keys= array;

}



/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/


/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/



// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [names release];
    [keys release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return [keys count];

}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{
    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *nameSection = [names objectForKey:key];
    return [nameSection count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *nameSection = [names objectForKey:key];

    static NSString *SectionTableIdentifier = @"SectionTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SectionTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:SectionTableIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

                cell.text = [nameSection objectAtIndex:row];
                return cell;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
    return key;

}
@end




**LOG:**



Build Sections of project Sections with configuration Debug

ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.app/Info.plist Sections-Info.plist
cd /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
builtin-infoPlistUtility Sections-Info.plist -genpkginfo /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.app/PkgInfo -expandbuildsettings -format binary -platform iphonesimulator -o /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.app/Info.plist

CompileXIB /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/MainWindow.xib
cd /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections
setenv IBC_MINIMUM_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION 4.2
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.app/MainWindow.nib /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/MainWindow.xib --sdk /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk

CompileXIB /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/SectionsViewController.xib
cd /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections
setenv IBC_MINIMUM_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION 4.2
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.app/SectionsViewController.nib /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/SectionsViewController.xib --sdk /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk

ProcessPCH /var/folders/6o/6oRlqcHSG3i+gabLJ+MCV++++TM/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.502/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/Sections_Prefix-gyjbjzxosthibsbszggxsbxqehxr/Sections_Prefix.pch.gch Sections_Prefix.pch normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_2
cd /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -x objective-c-header -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk -fexceptions -fvisibility=hidden -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40200 -iquote /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/Sections-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/Sections-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/Sections-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/Sections-project-headers.hmap -F/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -I/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/DerivedSources -c /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/Sections_Prefix.pch -o /var/folders/6o/6oRlqcHSG3i+gabLJ+MCV++++TM/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.502/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/Sections_Prefix-gyjbjzxosthibsbszggxsbxqehxr/Sections_Prefix.pch.gch

CompileC build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/main.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_2
cd /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk -fexceptions -fvisibility=hidden -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40200 -iquote /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/Sections-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/Sections-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/Sections-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/Sections-project-headers.hmap -F/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -I/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/DerivedSources -include /var/folders/6o/6oRlqcHSG3i+gabLJ+MCV++++TM/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.502/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/Sections_Prefix-gyjbjzxosthibsbszggxsbxqehxr/Sections_Prefix.pch -c /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/main.m -o /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o

CompileC build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/Objects-normal/i386/SectionsAppDelegate.o /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/Classes/SectionsAppDelegate.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_2
cd /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk -fexceptions -fvisibility=hidden -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40200 -iquote /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/Sections-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/Sections-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/Sections-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/Sections-project-headers.hmap -F/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -I/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/DerivedSources -include /var/folders/6o/6oRlqcHSG3i+gabLJ+MCV++++TM/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.502/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/Sections_Prefix-gyjbjzxosthibsbszggxsbxqehxr/Sections_Prefix.pch -c /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/Classes/SectionsAppDelegate.m -o /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/Objects-normal/i386/SectionsAppDelegate.o

CompileC build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/Objects-normal/i386/SectionsViewController.o Classes/SectionsViewController.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_2
cd /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk -fexceptions -fvisibility=hidden -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40200 -iquote /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/Sections-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/Sections-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/Sections-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/Sections-project-headers.hmap -F/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -I/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/DerivedSources -include /var/folders/6o/6oRlqcHSG3i+gabLJ+MCV++++TM/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.502/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/Sections_Prefix-gyjbjzxosthibsbszggxsbxqehxr/Sections_Prefix.pch -c /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/Classes/SectionsViewController.m -o /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/Objects-normal/i386/SectionsViewController.o

/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/Classes/SectionsViewController.m: In function '-[SectionsViewController viewDidLoad]':
/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/Classes/SectionsViewController.m:27: warning: incompatible Objective-C types 'struct NSArray *', expected 'struct NSDictionary *' when passing argument 1 of 'setKeys:' from distinct Objective-C type
/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/Classes/SectionsViewController.m: In function '-[SectionsViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]':
/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/Classes/SectionsViewController.m:99: warning: 'NSDictionary' may not respond to '-objectAtIndex:'
/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/Classes/SectionsViewController.m:99: warning: (Messages without a matching method signature
/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/Classes/SectionsViewController.m:99: warning: will be assumed to return 'id' and accept
/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/Classes/SectionsViewController.m:99: warning: '...' as arguments.)
/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/Classes/SectionsViewController.m: In function '-[SectionsViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]':
/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/Classes/SectionsViewController.m:110: warning: 'NSDictionary' may not respond to '-objectAtIndex:'
/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/Classes/SectionsViewController.m:120: warning: 'setText:' is deprecated (declared at /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UITableViewCell.h:211)
/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/Classes/SectionsViewController.m: In function '-[SectionsViewController tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:]':
/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/Classes/SectionsViewController.m:127: warning: 'NSDictionary' may not respond to '-objectAtIndex:'

Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.app/Sections normal i386
cd /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk -L/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Sections.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.build/Objects-normal/i386/Sections.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.app/Sections

GenerateDSYMFile build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.app.dSYM build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.app/Sections
cd /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.app/Sections -o /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.app.dSYM

Touch build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.app
cd /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/usr/bin/touch -c /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sections.app
```

Comment: Gah, codedump. Can you boil it down to what actually breaks, please?

Comment: "There are no bugs in the code" ?

Comment: I have fixed the formatting for you, in the future, please try and use proper formatting before you post.

Comment: How was your "keys" property declared in your header file ? It looks like you declared a NSDictionary instead of a NSArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's true - 'NSDictionary' does not respond to '-objectAtIndex:'

the compiler points out the source line of the problem, for example:
    SectionsViewController.m:99

and xcode will probably highlight it for you too.

Answer (score 2):

`NSDictionary`, According to the documentation, Should NOT respond to `objectAtIndex:`, which is a method for an `NSArray`. The equivalent for an `NSDictionary` would be `objectForKey:`.

Answer (score 1):

Given the almost complete lack of formatting in your post it's hard to see what the problem is. From the title of your question I would guess you are trying to call 'objectAtIndex' on a NSDictionary when you should be calling 'objectForKey'.

Answer (score 0):

`objectAtIndex:` is a method for arrays and it cannot be used for dictionary. You are trying to access an object in your dictionary somewhere in your class using `objectAtIndex:`. check if u are accessing it for `NSDictionary`

Answer (score 0):

Following the errors, you have `keys` declared as an NSDictionary when you want it to be an `NSArray`. Hence the warnings that you're assigning the wrong type of object on line 27, then making a possibly incompatible call on line 99.

You should check how you declare keys, which will be in the associated header file rather than in the code you've given. Solving just the first warning:

> /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/Classes/SectionsViewController.m:
>   In function '-[SectionsViewController
>   viewDidLoad]':
>   /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Sections/Classes/SectionsViewController.m:27:
>   warning: incompatible Objective-C
>   types 'struct NSArray *', expected
>   'struct NSDictionary *' when passing
>   argument 1 of 'setKeys:' from distinct
>   Objective-C type

Will solve all of them.